# Are my permissions set correctly? (python)

Tags: python, file-permissions

In python I'm doing a `os.system('chmod o+w filename.png')` command so I can overwrite the file with [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/index.html).

These are the permissions after I set them in python:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users 925 Sep 20 11:25 filename.png
```

Then I attempt:

```
os.system('pngcrush filename.png filename.png')
```

which is supposed to overwrite the file, but I get:

```
Cannot overwrite input file filename.png
```

What could be the problem? Isn't `pngcrush` being run as an 'other' user, for which write permissions are enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you execute the `pngcrush` program, not with permissions of `filename.png` or Python. It simply attempts to open `filename.png` both for input and output, which is of course invalid.

Give `pngcrush` either the `-e` or the `-d` option to tell it how to write output. Read its `man` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `pngcrush` isn't letting you use the same name for both input and output files? Have you tried changing the output filename? If so, what were the results?

Answer (score 2):

As an aside (not related to the problem of the input and output files being the same), you can change the mode of a file using `os.chmod`, which is more efficient than running `chmod`:

```
import os
import stat

path = "filename.png"
mode = os.stat(path).st_mode     # get current mode
newmode = mode | stat.S_IWOTH    # set the 'others can write' bit
os.chmod(path, newmode)          # set new mode
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're supposed to give a different (non-existing) filename for output. Have you tried the same in a shell?